# Java clientside socket can't regonize heroku server

Tags: java, android, sockets, heroku

I have setup a server running using ServerSocket on heroku. I know that heroku defines the port in a system defined variable, and I'm using that as well. Here is the snippet of the server code on Heroku.

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
try {
   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("PORT"));
   System.out.println("Booted server.  " + Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("PORT"));
   System.out.println(serverSocket);
} catch (IOException e) {
   System.err.println("Could not listen on port: " + Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("PORT"));
   System.exit(1);
}
Socket clientSocket = null;
    try {
        while (true) {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept()
            ConnectionHandler c = new ConnectionHandler(clientSocket);
        }
```

Running that and checking heroku logs shows that the server is running fine,

```
2013-11-22T03:02:21.940969+00:00 app[web.1]: Booted server.  40506
2013-11-22T03:02:21.953200+00:00 app[web.1]: ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=40506]
```

Next I'm running an android app, that requires to send/receive information. Here is the snippet of code that connects to the port.

```
clientSocket = new Socket(http://appname.herokuapp.com, 40506);
```

However I get the following in logcat on the above line:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "http://appname.herokuapp.com": No address associated with hostname
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:108)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
at com.example.taid.FullscreenActivity.CheckAccount(FullscreenActivity.java:241)
```

What's causing this error? Is that not the correct server address? On the server side, upon accepting a new connection I do have a print statement (testing purposes), and going to the url from web browser it prints the statement, so heroku accepts connection.

Also several things I noticed on Heroku:

1) Every few minutes the port gets incoming connections from a certain ip. During a single run, the ip is same with ports incrementing by 1. What are these connections? Can i stop them?

2) When I use the command to print the variable port (cmd > heroku run echo $PORT), I've realized this port is always different than what my server starts on. So is the problem with this line: System.getenv("PORT") ??

Any help is appreciated, been trying to troubleshoot this for toooooo long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're including a URL in  the hostname field.

You want the hostname:

```
clientSocket = new Socket("appname.herokuapp.com", 40506);
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Tried changing to this, which makes sense, but didn't make a difference.

Comment: Are you using the actual name of the app here?  I assumed appname is a placedholder.  If you lookup the DNS name of your app, "nslookup YOUR_ACTUAL_APP_NAME.herokuapp.com" - does it resolve?

Comment: Never mind, this actually worked! I just forgot to remove the very last '/' from the string. Although, the server still doesn't get the connection. But that's a different error. Answer accepted.

Comment: @slash I know this is really delayed but I think the port should be 80 or 443. Your application might be deployed at 40506 on the application server but to ping it via the hostname you'll need to go through the Heroku load balancer which has your app deployed at 443

Answer (score 0):

Couple of thoughts - note that the app hostname is not the name of the machine where your app is running. It's a pointer to Heroku's HTTP routing layer. For that reason, you won't be able to connect directly to that port anyway. Additionally, I believe Heroku uses AWS security groups to restrict network access to the actual dynos. Their network model is designed for HTTP/S access via their routing mesh. Any other kind of network access needs a different hosting solution.